# gulp not creating any files but finishes without any error

Tags: gulp, bower

I am trying to get all the files from bower_components and compressing them to on file like vendor.js and vendor.css.

I get no error when I execute the command glup vendor-build. Is there something I am doing wrong? I got the script from another stackoverflow question. I tried searching more to make my scrip work but couldn't find anything. I know there is something wrong I am missing.

**project dir structure**

[image]

**gulpfile.js**

```
var gulp = require('gulp');

// define plug-ins
var flatten = require('gulp-flatten');
var gulpFilter = require('gulp-filter');
var uglify = require('gulp-uglify');
var minifycss = require('gulp-minify-css');
var rename = require('gulp-rename');
var mainBowerFiles = require('main-bower-files');
var concat = require('gulp-concat');

// Define paths variables
var dest_path =  'app/static';

gulp.task('vendor-build', function() {

        var jsFilter = gulpFilter('*.js',  {restore: true});
        var cssFilter = gulpFilter('*.css',  {restore: true});
        var fontFilter = gulpFilter(['*.eot', '*.woff', '*.svg', '*.ttf']);

        return gulp.src(mainBowerFiles())
        .pipe(jsFilter)
        .pipe(concat('vendor.js'))
        .pipe(uglify())
        .pipe(rename({
            suffix: ".min"
        }))
        .pipe(gulp.dest(dest_path + '/js'))
        .pipe(jsFilter.restore)
        .pipe(cssFilter)
        .pipe(concat('vendor.css'))
        .pipe(minifycss())
        .pipe(rename({
            suffix: ".min"
        }))
        .pipe(gulp.dest(dest_path + '/css'))
        .pipe(cssFilter.restore)
        .pipe(fontFilter)
        .pipe(flatten())
        .pipe(gulp.dest(dest_path + '/fonts'));
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve by changing gulpFilter patter parameter. But I don't know why it solves the issue.

```
var jsFilter = gulpFilter('**/*.js',  {restore: true}); 
var lessFilter= gulpFilter('**/*.less', {restore: true}); 
var fontFilter = gulpFilter(['*.eot', '*.woff', '*.svg', '*.ttf']);
```